# Choice of server for local Django webapp?

Tags: django, webserver, localhost

I've put together a Django app that was intended to run on Pythonanywhere. However, I soon found out that Pythonanywhere's free plan blocks the remote sites which I intend to interact with, so I decided running the app on a local machine would be good enough for my purposes.

Now, I know that Django's development server isn't meant to be run in a production setting. So, what server daemon do I run on the aging Windows workstation the app's probably gonna be deployed to? Apache, lighttpd, Cherokee? Something else?

My first priority here is conserving system resources as much as I can; I'm probably also going to use Python's built-in sqlite3 instead of MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I deploy Django with [fcgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/) and [Nginx](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx). Nginx offers various strategies to conserve system resources; its use as [reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/30705/how-to-set-up-nginx-as-a-caching-reverse-proxy) is well documented and widely used.

The question/answer pair [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127342/nginx-flask-gunicorn-python-where-to-start/10127465) might help you clear some initial questions about the various components when deploying Django.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear you can't use PythonAnywhere's free version :-(

I'll second the usage of nginx; it's what we use as the front-end for PA.  However, we use uwsgi for the backend.  It works really well for us and is very easy to configure.